# Adding the dataframe name when looping over dataframes

Tags: python, for-loop, scikit-learn, knn

I wrote the following code to loop the same function over different dataframes (named "Drought", "Flashflood",etc).  I was happy to see that it worked, but I'm trying to determine how to get the names of the dataframes to append with the train and test scores.  Can someone please guide me on what I'm missing here?  If I do it like I currently have it, all the names post in each row at the bottom, but I only want the corresponding one.  Similarly, the output I get appends each new array together, but my understanding was that append would just add a new item to a list?

For example I'm getting this as a result:

```
[(0.11995478823013683, -0.07264567664161303), (0.11998113643282327, -0.034458152253100005)]
```

But I would expect this:

```
[("Drought",0.11995478823013683, -0.07264567664161303)]
[("Flashflood",0.11998113643282327, -0.034458152253100005)]
```

Here's the code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

df_list = [Drought, Flashflood, Flood, Gale]

names = ['Drought','Flashflood','Flood','Gale']

knn_r_acc = []
rmse_val = [] #to store rmse values for different dataframes
for df in df_list:
    X = df[['Year.Month','IDH.M_2000','Population','IDH.M_2010']]
    y = df['Deceased'].values
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    #Scaling
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

    x_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
    x_train = pd.DataFrame(x_train_scaled)

    x_test_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
    x_test = pd.DataFrame(x_test_scaled)

    model = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = 3, weights = 'uniform')

    model.fit(x_train, y_train)  #fit the model
    pred=model.predict(x_test) #make prediction on test set
    error = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,pred)) #calculate rmse
    rmse_val.append(error) #store rmse values
    #print('Model= ' , df, 'is:', error)

    knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
    test_score = knn.score(X_test,y_test)
    train_score = knn.score(X_train,y_train)
    #print(test_score)
    #print(train_score)

    knn_r_acc.append((names,train_score, test_score))

    print(knn_r_acc)
```

Comment: Instead of using something pandas-related, why not iterate both lists (`dataframes` and `names`) at the same time? `for name, df in zip(names, df_list):`. This assumes that they're in the same order

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `names` is actually a whole list / array.

You can implement it using an index variable. So before the loop starts, add:

```
name_index = 0
```

and inside the loop, append like so:

```
knn_r_acc.append((names[name_index], train_score, test_score))
name_index += 1
```